# Static function can not be accessed or used C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, static-classes

I am trying to use a static class, but for some reason I am getting a really not helpful error.

This is the static class I am trying to access:

```
static class Camera
{

public:
    Camera();
    ~Camera();

    static glm::mat4 viewMatrix;

    static void move(float x, float y, float z) {// add 3 more values for the cube
        viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(x, y, z),glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    } 


    static glm::mat4 getViewMatrix() {
        return viewMatrix;
    }
};
```

This is the way I am trying to access a function:

```
 Camera::move(xdist, ydist, zdist);
```

The error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static struct glm::detail::tmat4x4<float> Camera::viewMatrix" (?viewMatrix@Camera@@2U?$tmat4x4@M@detail@glm@@A) sample
```

Comment: Since static members needs to be initialized once at program startup, you need to create a `.cpp` file with the following definition: `glm::mat4 Camera::viewMatrix(parameters_here);`

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé viewMatrix does not take any parameters. Also, this is part of the class what do you mean by creating another .cpp

Comment: The linked duplcated question is very broad and does not give any clue on how OP should fix his problem. A better linked question/answer should be provided.

Comment: Just wondering can you try to initialize the static variable to something like this in this example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé, the problem of `static` class members described in the second answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/434551.

Comment: What is a static class? This is not C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit maybe C# or even Java.  Definitely means that the question identified as duplicate is irrelevant.

Comment: In C++, a "static class" has no meaning. You have to define [static members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/static-members-cpp?view=vs-2019) in your cpp file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, added this to the cpp file:

```
 glm::mat4 Camera::viewMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
```

Needed to initialize the viewMatrix in the .cpp not in the .h file